# Redshift free storage doesn't increase after adding 2 nodes

Tags: amazon-redshift

My 4-Node (`dc2.large 160 GB` storage per node)  Redshift cluster had around 75% storage full, so I added 2 more nodes, to make a total of 6 Nodes, and I was expecting the disk usage to drop down to around 50%, but after making the said change, the disk usage still remains at 75% (even after few days and after `VACUUM`).

75% of 4*160 = 480 GB of data

6*160 = 960 of available storage in the new configuration, which means it should have dropped to 480/960 i.e somewhere close to 50% disk usage.

The image shows the disk space percentage before and after adding two nodes.
[image]

I also checked if there are any large table which are using `DISTSTYLE ALL`, which causes data replication across the nodes, but the tables I have in that are very small in size as compared to the total storage capacity, so I don't think they'd have any significant impact on the storage.

[image]

What can I do here to reduce the storage usage as I don't want to add more nodes and then again land up in the same situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your tables are affected by the minimum table size. It may be counter-intuitive but you can often reduce the size of small tables by converting them to DISTSTYLE ALL.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redshift-cluster-storage-space/

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify what distribution style you are using for some of the bigger tables?

If you are not specifying a distribution style then Redshift will automatically pick one (see [here](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/03/amazon-redshift-now-automatically-picks-the-best-distribution-st/)), and it's possible that it will chose `ALL` distribution at first and only switch to `EVEN` or `KEY` distribution once you reach a certain disk usage %.

Also, have you run the `ANALYZE` command to make sure the table stats are up to date?

Comment: Only few tables are `DISTSTYLE ALL`, and I've shared the storage used by them in the above screenshot. The larger tables I have are mostly using `DISTSTYLE KEY`